# Error during the deploy with wildfly-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, ejb, wildfly

I have a Maven multimodule project with the following structure:

```
- cotacao
-- cotacao-core
-- cotacao-service
```

The `cotacao`project is the root, and `cotacao-{core,service}` are modules. The `cotacao-service` is an EJB module that has the `cotacao-core` as a dependency.  I'm using `wildfly-maven-plugin` to deploy the EJB `cotacao-service` .

Snippets of my `pom.xml`are:

(1) The `cotacao` project:

```
<groupId>com.tnas</groupId>
<artifactId>cotacao</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>Cotacao Parent Project</name>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>cotacao-service</module>
    <module>cotacao-core</module>
</modules>
```

(2) The `cotacao-core` project:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.tnas</groupId>
    <artifactId>cotacao</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.fincatto</groupId>
<artifactId>cotacao-core</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>Cotacao Core</name>
```

(3) The `cotacao-service` project:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.tnas</groupId>
    <artifactId>cotacao</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>cotacao-service</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>ejb</packaging>
...
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fincatto</groupId>
        <artifactId>cotacao</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>  
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${wildfly.plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>deploy-cotacao-core-dependency</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy-artifact</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                        <project>
                            <dependencies>
                                <dependency>
                                    <groupId>com.fincatto</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>cotacao-core</artifactId>
                                </dependency>
                            </dependencies>
                        </project>
            </configuration>                    
        </plugin>
        ...
      </plugins>
   </build>
```

I'm running the followin Maven goal `wildfly:deploy` and I'm getting the error:

```
15:34:03,183 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 36) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "cotacao-service-1.0.0.jar" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"cotacao-service-1.0.0.jar\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"cotacao-service-1.0.0.jar\".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"cotacao-service-1.0.0.jar\"
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class com.tnas.cotacao.service.BACENService with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module \"deployment.cotacao-service-1.0.0.jar:main\" from Service Module Loader
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/fincatto/cotacao/ws/WSConsulta;
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fincatto.cotacao.ws.WSConsulta from [Module \"deployment.cotacao-service-1.0.0.jar:main\" from Service Module Loader]"},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"cotacao-service-1.0.0.jar\".POST_MODULE"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined
}
```

So, I don't know what's the problem with my Maven configurations. How can I use the `wildfly-maven-plugin` in order to deploy an EJB with the respective dependencies? In my case, the `cotacao-core` is one of the required dependencies.

Thanks!

Comment: This is not going to work the way it stands. Separate deployments are isolated from each other by default, so even if you do deploy the `cotacao-core` jar, `cotacao-service` will not be able to see the classes in it.

Comment: But, is there a way to do what I want? Or is it not possible?

Comment: Why not just use an EAR?

Answer (score 0):

You must 'cotacao-core' installed before do wildfly:deploy:

Try to change execution to install:

```
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fincatto</groupId>
        <artifactId>cotacao-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${wildfly.plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>deploy-cotacao-core-dependency</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy-artifact</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>                    
                    <groupId>com.fincatto</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cotacao-service</artifactId>
                   </dependency>                            
            </configuration>                    
        </plugin>
        ...
      </plugins>
```

And  simply launches : mvn install

Comment: After this change, I'm getting the error: `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.2.0.Final:deploy-artifact (deploy-cotacao-core-dependency) on project cotacao-service: deploy-artifact must specify the artifactId`

Comment: try  mvn clean install -DartifactId=cotacao-service

Answer (score 0):

I've not found out an elegant way of doing what I want. So, I've worked around this problem with the `maven-shade-plugin`. The plugin was configured as follow. There are two executions: one for the EJB itself, and another one for the EJB client.

```
        <!-- Usage: mvn:package -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${shade.plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>shade-ejb-service</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputFile>${ejb.fileName}.jar</outputFile>
                        <artifactSet>
                            <includes>
                                <!-- Here I've included every dependencies -->
                                <include>groupId:artifactId</include>
                            </includes>
                        </artifactSet>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>shade-ejb-client</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputFile>${ejb.fileName}-client.jar</outputFile>
                        <artifactSet>
                            <includes>
                                <!-- Only dependencies for the client -->
                                <include>groupId:artifactId</include>
                            </includes>
                        </artifactSet>
                        <!-- Filters for selecting specific client classes -->
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>com.fincatto:cotacao-core</artifact>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>com/fincatto/cotacao/classes/*</include>
                                </includes>
                            </filter>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>com.tnas:cotacao-service</artifact>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>com/tnas/cotacao/service/remote/*</include>
                                </includes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Do you know what an EAR file is?